# combine-function with list-comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I've a simple question:

```
combine :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
combine f (a:as) (b:bs) =  f a b : combine f as bs
combine _  _ _      = [ ]
```

This is recursive. Now i want to use a list comprehension to solve the same problem:

```
combine f (x:xs) (y:ys) = [ f x y  | x <- (x:xs), y <- (y:ys) ]
```

But my problem is the combination of elements. I only want to combine `x1 y1, x2 y2, xs ys ...` not `x1 y1, x1 y2, x1 ys, x2 y1, x2 y2, .....`.

Thank you!

Comment: This function is better known as `zipWith`. You could implement it with a list comprehension as follows: `combine f xs ys = [ f x y | (x, y) <- zip xs ys ]`

Comment: thank you, now the function works! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is a [parallel list compehension](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/5.00/set/parallel-list-comprehensions.html). To be able to use it you need to specify a `ParallelListComp` pragma to the compiler:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}

combine :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
combine f xs ys = [ f x y | x <- xs | y <- ys ]
```

Compiler desugars it to an application of `zipWith`:

```
combine :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
combine f xs ys = zipWith f xs ys
```

Which is actually what your function is, so:

```
combine :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
combine = zipWith
```

Comment: Nice one, I didn't know about that. A good new way to confuse my collegues I guess since it looks very similar to `[ f x y | x <- xs , y <- ys ]` but does something completely different :)

Answer (score 2):

Since list comprehension usually gives Cartesian product, you can also try [ZipList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html) from `Control.Applicative`

```
GHCi> :m + Control.Applicative
GHCi> :info ZipList
newtype ZipList a = ZipList {getZipList :: [a]}
    -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
instance Functor ZipList -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
instance Applicative ZipList -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
GHCi> let combine f xs ys = getZipList $ f <$> ZipList xs <*> ZipList ys
GHCi> :t combine 
combine :: (a2 -> a1 -> a) -> [a2] -> [a1] -> [a]
GHCi> combine (-) [10,9..] [1..10]
[9,7,5,3,1,-1,-3,-5,-7,-9]
GHCi>
```

Don't fear of `ZipList`, it just wraps a list, you can convert a list into `ZipList` and convert it back using `getZipList`. 
[This chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) in LYAH gives you some explanation about how to use it, have fun!

BTW, you can use a bare list in the example above, which gives you the Cartesian product:

```
GHCi> let combine1 f xs ys = f <$> xs <*> ys

GHCi> :t combine1
combine1 :: Applicative f => (a1 -> a -> b) -> f a1 -> f a -> f b
GHCi> combine (-) [10,9..1] [1..10]
[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,...]
GHCi>
```

As you can see, there are two ways of merging two lists together, one is to think elements in a list as possible results, if you take one possible value from `xs=[1,2]`, and another possible value from `ys=[3,4]` to make a tuple, you will end up with all possibilities: `[(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)]`, this is basically what `[(x,y)| x <- xs, y <-ys]` is saying. But there is also another way of merging two lists: every time you take one element simultaneously from two lists, and make a pair, until one of the list reaches its end, this is how `ZipList` get merged together.

Answer (score 0):

this would be my poor answer

```
kk :: ( a -> b -> c) -> (a,b) -> c 
kk f (x,y) = f x y 

combineFunk :: (a ->  b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
combineFunk f xs ys = [cs | (a,b)  <- zip xs ys  , let  cs = kk f (a,b) ]
```

Comment: `cs = kk f (a,b) = f a b` so you could just [write `f a b` directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384704/combine-function-with-list-comprehension/60134647#comment32252076_21384704) instead of defining and using `cs`. also, `kk` is a built-in function,  `uncurry`.